# Displaying scheduled text messages and icon widget on home screen

Tags: sms, automation, app-widgets

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone. When using the SMS application, it is possible to schedule a text message (for instance, it might be night, and you don't want to wake the receiver up, so you schedule it to be sent automatically during the day).

However, it may be, that the phone powers off, and, then, the user is asked whether to send the message when powered on or if it is sent automatically if not too late (as configured in the global app or per message settings).

However, you can do better: on the lock screen, you can display an icon saying that a message is to be sent, so, that the user, may not disconnect the phone from the charger, play a video that sucks out the battery, place the phone on the sofa, and then the message is sent late. Instead, if an icon is placed on the home screen, the user will not view the video, and the phone will stay connected to the battery charger, (and, in the morning, when the time to send the message comes, the message will be sent, unless there is a power outage).

Next to the icon, there should be a queue scrollable horizontally, but for this purpose, where you can also view the exact times when the message is pending (and, decide, this way, whether to disconnect the phone from the plug and view a bit of video far away from the plug in the wall, or not).

In this case, if the phone has an LED, you may want to leave it on during charging or change its color (and the screen could be blanked instead of turned off with an icon displayed, but this could be configured in the app (which would need to be given a special Android permission to do this).

Is this functionality available in Android?